# When I switch back to no-changes branch, VS rebuilds the project. How to track build-files but not push them?

Tags: git, visual-studio, build, gitignore

In my repo setup, I have all the build files ignored. So basically I am not interested in tracking all the files that get generated when I build my project, for example *.exe.

In the below scenario, my project rebuilds from scratch in step 8. I would like it to not build since nothing has changed in that branch, and its version of the build files are their from step 2. But I also don't want to push those files.

So technically I want to track those build files so that VS "knows" and not build, but also not track so that they don't get pushed to the remote repo.

Is there a way to achieve this but also keep the "diff" minimal?

> 1 - Checkout master
>
> 2 - Build (shows that it started from scratch)
>
> 3 - Build again (shows "everything up to date")
>
> 4 - Checkout OtherBranch
>
> 5 - Commit some change
>
> 6 - Build (starts from scratch)
>
> 7 - Checkout master
>
> 8 - Build (starts from scratch)

Comment: Perhaps you should look at worktrees instead of trying to jerryrig your repository.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I see. Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: Worktrees allows you to have more than one branch checked out at the same time, all back by the same local repository. This allows you to work on multiple branches simultaneously, as they reside in different folders. This would reduce the number of times you need to switch branches in the same folder. Of course, this will occupy more disk space, but each folder would have its own relevant build output and caches. See [git-worktree Documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) for more information.

Comment: Note that since worktrees are backed by the same local repository, you can do a commit on one folder, immediately go to the other folder and merge that commit into that branch. You do not have to push/pull etc. between these as, other than being separate folders, they are the same repository and behave as 1.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen I see, I will play with it on a temp repo and see how it goes. Thanks for the info!